# How can I create a function which accepts a function with specific parameters as an argument?

Tags: function, dart, type-systems

I'd like to create a function which accepts a function that accepts specific types of parameters as an argument. For example:

```
myFn(Function paramFn) {
    paramFn([1, 2, 3]);
}
```

How can I ensure that paramFn accepts a `List<int>` as an only parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `typedef` to associate a symbol with a function that satisfies the signature you want. Something like

```
typedef void ParamFn(List<int> l);

myFn(ParamFn f) {
  f('abc');   // compile time error
  f([1,2,3]); // works fine
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `typedef` to define the signature you want like described in [Kul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664714/634863) or you can simply inline the function signature in the parameter:

```
myFn(void paramFn(List<int> l)) {
  paramFn([1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what [typedefs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) are for, although I'm not sure how rigid the strong mode will enforce it yet.